# finding the sum of digits?

Tags: c, sum-of-digits

I tried this problem using for loop but i did not got the correct output as specified . i do not know what is the problem in my code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    int T,N;    
    scanf("%d %d" ,&T,&N);

    for(int i=N;i>0;i=i/10)
    {
        int r=N%10;
        int sum=0;
        sum=sum+r;
        printf("The sum is : %d" ,sum);   
    }    
}
```

The sum is : 5The sum is : 5The sum is : 5The sum is : 5The sum is : 5

The output is coming like this while we just need sum of digits printed

Comment: Sounds like you want the print to be outside of the loop instead.

Comment: You do the same calculation over and over again. `sum` will always be equal to `N%10` so you print the same value in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @churill Sir , I didn't got you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried my best to ask the question in good manner.  Please help me if there is something wrong

Comment: And by the way, you can find *working* code for this problem with 5 seconds of googling.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it's C . Used C++ by mistake . Sorry

Comment: Also @RitikSrivastava you'd do well to accept the oldest answer, which explains it well.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = N; i > 0 ; i = i/10)
{
    int r = N % 10; // calculating remainder of UNMODIFIED input, so will
                    // ALWAYS be last digit

    int sum = 0;    // you are initializing the sum to 0 for every single iteration

    sum = sum + r;  // so this will *always* result in 0 + N % 10

    printf("The sum is : %d", sum);
}
```

To fix, you need to initialise the sum just *once* to collect all of the single digits. Additionally, you need to use the *modified* value:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = N; i > 0 ; i = i/10)
{
    int r = i % 10;
    //      ^  (!)
    sum += r; // alternative variant...
    printf("The sum is : %d\n", sum);
    //                     ^^ for better output formatting
}
```

Until now we are still printing the sum with every iteration as well. That *might* be useful, if you want to follow how the sum evolves (assuming input was 1210):

```
The sum is 0
The sum is 1
The sum is 3
The sum is 4
```

But actually, you'd rather want to print only the result, wouldn't you? So you'd move the printing out of the loop as well:

```
for(...)
{
    ...
}
printf("The sum is : %d\n", sum);
```

Alternative variant: If you don't need the value of N afterwards any more anyway, you can iterate directly on it:

```
for(  ; N > 0; N /= 10)
//  ^ empty initialization, nothing to be done...
{
    int r = N % 10; // NOW using N is fine...
    ...
}
```

Finally: if you compare with `!=` instead of `>`, you can cover negative intput (as you use *signed* integers...) as well.

*Edit according to question:*

> it asked input and output like this. Input 3 12345 31203 2123 Output 15 9 8

Well, in this case, you need a double loop:

```
int t;
// well, actually, you should check if you did get correct input:
if(scanf("%d", &t) != 1))
{
    // invalid input
    // appropriate error handling, e. g. printing a message and:
    return -1;
}

for( ; t > 0; --t) // handles the number of tasks to solve
{
    int n; // inside loop: read in a new value with every task
    scanf("%d", &n); // TODO: check input, see above

    int sum = 0;
    for(...) { ... } // loop handling the input value, see above
    printf(...);
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate your effort to guide me . i want to ask a doubt . i was solving this on codechef , i made the required changes u suggested but still its saying wrong answer when i submit . See it asked input and output like this.                                           Input
3 
12345
31203
2123
Output
15
9
8 . where 3 is the number of test cases we need to take as input

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main()
                                                                                                   {                                                                                                          
                                                                                                
 int T;
    scanf("%d" ,&T);
    int N;
    scanf("%d" ,&N);
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=N;i>0;i=i/10)
    {
        
        
       int r=i%10;
       sum=sum+r;
       continue;
    }

    printf("%d\n" ,sum);
}

Comment: @RitikSrivastava See edits; in your comment: Why would you want a continue inside the loop? There's nothing to skip afterwards anyway...